# Highlight months in material UI date Picker

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

does anyone knows how could I highligth a row of months in material UI Date Picker, to look as it follows. The point is that it would show me the selected quarter.
thank you so much in advance!
Right now I have the following set up on the date picker

```html
<DatePicker
        className="range-picker"
        variant="inline"
        views={["year", "month"]}
        margin="normal"
        id="date-picker-dialog"
        label="texto"
        autoOk={true}
        style={{ fill: "#C83771" }}
        value={selectedDate}
        KeyboardButtonProps={{
          "aria-label": "change date"
        }}
      />
```

[How it is suposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD2FH.png)

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker has ability to be customised through `slots`. Unfortunately, there's no month view or any month components in `slots` options.

[So, here there's my solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datepicker-with-quarter-highlight-kgnfp8):

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";


const quarterSets = [
 [0, 1, 2],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [9, 10, 11]
];

const Picker = () => {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(dayjs());
  const months = document.getElementsByClassName("MuiPickersMonth-root");

  const clearMonthsHighlight = () => {
    Array.from(months).forEach((month) => {
      month.style.backgroundColor = "unset";
    });
  };

  const highlightQuarter = (selectedMonthNumber) => {
    const quarterSet = quarterSets.find((set) =>
      set.includes(selectedMonthNumber)
    );
    quarterSet.forEach((monthNumber) => {
      months[monthNumber].style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    });
  };

  const onMonthChange = (e) => {
    clearMonthsHighlight();
    highlightQuarter(e.month());
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
        className="range-picker"
        variant="inline"
        views={["year", "month"]}
        margin="normal"
        id="date-picker-dialog"
        label="texto"
        autoOk={true}
        style={{ fill: "#C83771" }}
        value={selectedDate}
        KeyboardButtonProps={{
          "aria-label": "change date"
        }}
        onMonthChange={onMonthChange}
        onChange={setSelectedDate}
        closeOnSelect={false}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
};

export default Picker;
```